# Display value in Database DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, petapoco

This is my Query =>

```
var department = dataContext.Query<Department>("SELECT Id FROM tblDepartment");
```

I want to display the values in variable Department in ViewBag or Anywhere.How can I do that?

Comment: And what is the problem? `ViewBag.Department = department` in your `Controller`

Comment: @teovankot And how to display that values in my VIEW.When I gave ViewBag.Department it shows like "PetaPoco.Database+<Query>d__2`1[PetaPoco.Models.Department]"

Comment: var department = dataContext.Query<Department>("SELECT Id FROM tblDepartment").ToList() and then work with list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var department = dataContext.Query<Department>("SELECT Id FROM tblDepartment").ToList()
```

and then work with list

Answer (score 1):

You can use **linq to Entities** without executing raw queries as:

```
var department = dataContext.Department.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList();
```

If you are stubborn to use raw query, you can use as teo van kot has suggested above:

```
var department = dataContext.Query<Department>("SELECT Id FROM tblDepartment").ToList();
```

You can assign the list to `ViewBag` in controller as:

```
ViewBag.DepartmentIDs = department;
```

You can display the values in View as:

```
@{

foreach(var item in ViewBag.DepartmentIDs)
{
<span>@item <br/></span>
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with LinQ as I'm new to field.It says I can't type dataContext.Department..Why would be that?

Comment: Check the instance of Department you have in your framework. It should be like:

`public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppContext () : ;

    public DbSet<Department> Department{ get; set; }   
}`